# Separate subset columns from a file to sub files

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, csv, subset

I have a little task that I am struggling with. So basically we have to read columns from a TSV file and export all possible subsets of the columns to a CSV. Before exporting we have to sanitize the code (remove special chars except .,spaces).

I came across this subset code but I am not sure how to utilize it with my requirement:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain, combinations


def all_subsets(ss):

    return chain(*map(lambda x: combinations(ss,x), range(0, len(ss) + 1)))
subsets = all_subsets([1, 2, 3, 4])

for subset in subsets:

   print(subset)
```

[Pictorial Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGjxk.png)

Comment: `[1, 2, 3, 4]` are columns names?

Comment: @jezrael Yes There are Four Columns A ,B ,C ,D (names are for reference)

Comment: Do you understand what that function does, or how to call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need select columns by subset, processes and write to files:

```
df = pd.read_table(file)

#clean DataFrame by regex

#return list of all comprination of columns names
subsets = all_subsets(df.columns)

for subset in subsets:
    df1 = df[list(subset)]
    #join values of tuples to files names
    df1.to_csv('_'.join(subset) + '.csv', index=False)
```

EDIT:

For add column `acm_classification` to `Dataframe` use:

```
df = pd.read_table('xa.tsv')
print (df.head())

def all_subsets(ss):

    return chain(*map(lambda x: combinations(ss,x), range(0, len(ss) + 1)))

cols = [x for x in df.columns if not x == 'acm_classification']
subsets = all_subsets(cols)
#print (subsets)

for subset in subsets:
    #filter subsets
    if len(subset) > 1:
        df1 = df[list(subset) + ['acm_classification']]
#        print (df1)     
        df1.to_csv('_'.join(subset) + '.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'columns' Getting this Error

Comment: @FaqahatFareed - Do you create dataframe by `df = pd.read_table(file)` ?

Comment: Thanks alot, it worked, but Can youaloso assist with Removing Special characters from the text using regex before exporting to subfiles?

Comment: @FaqahatFareed - I think better is create new question, I dont feel like regex expert. simply regex understand, but more complicated it is really hard for me. thank you.

Comment: Hey, Sorry i forgot to mention there is a column called "acm_classification" i have to add it to every subset. how can that be done in this code

Comment: @FaqahatFareed - You can use `df[["acm_classification"] + list(subset)]`

Comment: When i added this. it only created only 4 Sets (single columns)

Comment: @FaqahatFareed - Do you need combination of all columns without `acm_classification`, which has to be in each separate dataframe?

Comment: No i just need to concatenate the acm_classifications columns with all the export files

Comment: @FaqahatFareed so if `df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'acm_classification':range(6)})

print (df)
`

Comment: @FaqahatFareed then need `df = df.drop('acm_classification', 1).astype(str).add(df['acm_classification'].astype(str), axis=0);
print (df)` ?

Comment: I'm not quite getting it  will this add that colomn to every export?
{A,X}
{A,B,X}
{A,B,C,X}
{A,B,C,D,X}
{B,X}
so on where X is acm_classification

Comment: Thanks, But what liberary does difference come from AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'difference'

Comment: please check now `cols = np.setdiff1d(df.columns, ['acm_classification'])`

Comment: File "subset.py", line 10, in <module>
    cols = np.setdiff1d(df.columns, ['acm_classification'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py", line 444, in setdiff1d
    ar1 = unique(ar1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py", line 196, in unique
    ar.sort()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 816, in sort
    raise TypeError('Cannot sort an %r object' % self.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Cannot sort an 'Index' object

Comment: OK, so pure python solution `cols = [x for x in df.columns if not x == 'acm_classification']`

Comment: Bro this is only exporting the colomns (single ones ) like {A,X} {B,X} {C,X} not {A,B,X} , {C,D,X} etc

Comment: @FaqahatFareed - I add sample data - for me it working nice. Can you check it?

Comment: http://faqahat.me/xa.rar here is the file bro give it a try you will see

Comment: @FaqahatFareed - Can you check now?

Comment: Rhanks it works but i still have a query. It makes Suplicates Subets like

{1,2,3,4}
It will also make
{4,2,3,1}
same contecnt different sequence can we avoid that?

Comment: So we can only have minimal combinations without duplicates

Comment: @FaqahatFareed - for me it working very nice, I get unique combination. Ca nyou test it with small data set? Or maybe some duplicates columns names

Comment: Works Perfectly Fine! Thanks alot. Just last thing. it creates this blank file. http://prntscr.com/isubbc can it be avoided?

Comment: @FaqahatFareed - do you use condition `if len(subset) > 1:` like 4 line of code from bottom?

Comment: Thanks, i removed it because it was not doing the single {A} , {B} ,{C} etc. so i had to change to if len(subset) > 0: It worked Fine now ! thanks alot!!

Comment: As for Removing Special Chars, Can this be done without Regex using any pandas function to do that?

Comment: @FaqahatFareed - I think the best is create new question ;) thanks. But obviosuly is regex necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I did create a new Thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49349079/remove-special-chars-from-a-tsv-file-using-regex

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

```
In [85]: cols = ['col1','col2','col3','col4']

In [86]: all_combinations = list(chain(*[list(combinations(cols, i))
                                 for i in range(2, len(cols)+1)]))

In [87]: all_combinations
Out[87]:
[('col1', 'col2'),
 ('col1', 'col3'),
 ('col1', 'col4'),
 ('col2', 'col3'),
 ('col2', 'col4'),
 ('col3', 'col4'),
 ('col1', 'col2', 'col3'),
 ('col1', 'col2', 'col4'),
 ('col1', 'col3', 'col4'),
 ('col2', 'col3', 'col4'),
 ('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4')]
```

Comment: NameError: name 'lst' is not defined

Answer (score 2):

There are `2 ** n` total combinations of `n` things.  I'll use the fact that every combination of `n` things can be represented by the presence of a `1` or `0` in the binary representation of every number from `0` to `2 ** n - 1`.

```
def all_subsets(n):
    for i in range(1, 2 ** n):
        yield np.array(list(f'{i:0{n}b}'), int).astype(bool)

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4]], columns=list('ABCD'))

print(*(df.loc[:, m].to_csv() for m in all_subsets(df.shape[1])), sep='\n')
```

---

```
,D
0,4

,C
0,3

,C,D
0,3,4

,B
0,2

,B,D
0,2,4

,B,C
0,2,3

,B,C,D
0,2,3,4

,A
0,1

,A,D
0,1,4

,A,C
0,1,3

,A,C,D
0,1,3,4

,A,B
0,1,2

,A,B,D
0,1,2,4

,A,B,C
0,1,2,3

,A,B,C,D
0,1,2,3,4
```