# Remove Special Chars from a TSV file using Regex

Tags: python, regex, file, csv

I have a File called "X.tsv" i want to remove special characters (including double spaces) (excluding .  Single spaces Tabs / -) using regex before i export them to sub files in python

I want to implement it in the following code.

```
import pandas as pd 
import csv
from itertools import chain, combinations 
df = pd.read_table('xa.tsv')
def all_subsets(ss): 
    return chain(*map(lambda x: combinations(ss,x), range(0, len(ss) + 1)))

cols = [x for x in df.columns if not x == 'acm_classification'    if not x== 'publicationId'    if not x== 'publisher'    if not x== 'publication_link'    if not x== 'source'] # Exclude Extra Cols
subsets = all_subsets(cols)
for subset in subsets: 
    if len(subset) > 0: #
        df1 = df[list(subset) + ['acm_classification']]
        df1.to_csv('_'.join(subset) + '.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Please add an example TSV file into your question and show what the resulting output file should look like.

Comment: http://faqahat.me/xa.rar here is table, I want to remove all the special characters exculding (single spaces . -)

Comment: Thanks. Can you expand your definition of special characters? i.e. give examples.

Comment: @MartinEvans Like " , $!@#$%^&*()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `read_csv()` to help with loading the TSV file. You could then specify the columns you want to keep and for it to use `\t` as the delimiter:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def normalise(text):
    text = re.sub('[{}]'.format(re.escape('",$!@#$%^&*()')), ' ', text.strip())  # Remove special characters
    text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text)        # Convert multiple whitespace into a single space
    return text

fieldnames = ['title', 'abstract', 'keywords', 'general_terms', 'acm_classification']
df = pd.read_csv('xa.tsv', delimiter='\t', usecols=fieldnames, dtype='object', na_filter=False)
df = df.applymap(normalise)
print(df)
```

You can then use `df.applymap()` to apply a function to each cell to format it as you need. In this example it first removes any leading or trailing spaces, converts multiple whitespace characters into a single space and also removes your list of special characters.

The resulting dataframe could then be further processed using your `all_subsets()` function before saving.